# Crazy eights use of 8 to keep suit

Tags: crazy8s

In crazy 8’s can you use an 8 to change the suit of the game to the suit that is currently being played. For example, if the current play is clubs can you you use the 8 of spades and state “clubs”.

Comment: You certainly can keep the suit the same in Uno and this is explicitly made clear in the rules.  From the rules on the Mattel website, "*Wild Card - When you play this card, you may change the color being played to any other color (including the current color) to continue play...*"  Granted, Uno is much more recent (1970's vs 1930's*) but both follow almost identical rules in many aspects.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a definitive set of rules. It's a game learned through word of mouth over generations. And house rules are easily added. All this means that not everyone plays by the same rules. Ultimately, the answer comes down to whatever rules the group agreed to use.

What? You didn't agree to a set of rules? ;) Well, the Wikipedia page for [Crazy Eights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Eights) has no variant listed concerning the functioning of eights. It only lists the following rule:

> They can also play any 8 at any time, which allows them to declare the suit that the next player is to play; that player must then follow the named suit or play another 8.

And [this version](https://www.pagat.com/eights/crazy8s.html) of the rules says:

> An Eight may be played on any card, and the player of the Eight must nominate a suit.

In both cases, no limit is mentioned concerning the stated suit. Words such as "other" and "change" that would imply a different suit should be picked are conspicuously absent. This means the suit already being played is a valid choice.

This is consistent with how I played.

Comment: ("At any time" is a poor choice of words.)